# Merge rows by ID in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I've got a set of columns like this in excel:

```
ID                                      sizeAndColourAndSku_Value
2ff0d3d7-8c18-4386-83be-1b2485fb4ea9    Select size
2ff0d3d7-8c18-4386-83be-1b2485fb4ea9    Extra Small - Available (only 1 left)
2ff0d3d7-8c18-4386-83be-1b2485fb4ea9    Small - Available (only 2 left)
2ff0d3d7-8c18-4386-83be-1b2485fb4ea9    Medium - Available (only 2 left)
2ff0d3d7-8c18-4386-83be-1b2485fb4ea9    Large - Available (only 1 left)
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    Select size
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    6 - Available (only 2 left)
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    8 - Available (only 4 left)
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    10 - Available (only 6 left)
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    12 - Available (only 6 left)
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    14 - Available (only 4 left)
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    16 - Available (only 2 left)
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    Select size
```

I need to combine merge them by their ID so the results become like this:

```
2ff0d3d7-8c18-4386-83be-1b2485fb4ea9   Extra Small  Small  Medium  Large
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95   6      8      10     12      14
```

I read here that the quickest and easiest way to do this is with a pivot table in excel

http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=235727

However I'm using excel 2010 and the method they've provided doesn't really work, anyone able to help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: Asked on SU as well [here](http://superuser.com/q/629480/219090).

Comment: yea, cause I posted this before and nobody answered on SU and I really need some help on this one. Sorry about the double post, but I'm pretty desperate as this is for a client's project

Answer (score 0):

If you pivot on this data range and apply the ID field to 'Row Labels' and the sizeAndColourAndSku_Value field to both 'Column Labels' and 'Values' you will get something similar, except it will give you a count of the occurrences rather than the values themselves.

Comment: Not really... you'll get as many headers as there are sizes, meaning 4 from the first, 5 for the second and for the sample, there'll be total 9 columns!

Comment: yea I noticed that, that's the problem, I need the values themselves rather than the count.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an answer to this somewhere on SE (I wrote it but can't find it!) however:

1. Parse your `sizeAndColourAndSku_Value` column with Text to Columns and `-` as the delimiter.
2. Delete rows with `Select size`.
3. Assuming the  `Extra Small` part of `Extra Small- Available (only 1 left)` is now in B2 put:

`=IF(COLUMN()<COUNTIF($A:$A,$A2)+3,IF($A2=$A3,INDIRECT("$B"&ROW()+COLUMN()-3),""),"")`

in  C2 and copy across and down to suit.

4. Select entire sheet and Paste Special Values over the top.
5. In B2 put: `=A1=A2` and copy down to suit.
6. Filter ColumnB for TRUE and delete visible rows.
7. Delete ColumnB.

*Edit to add image:*

[image: SO18126815 example]

Comment: I got to the step: "in C2 and copy across and down to suit". But in step 1 "Select entire sheet and Paste Special Values over the top", I'm slightly confused, what do I need to Paste Special Values over?

Comment: okay in step the 2nd step 2, I placed `=A1=A2` and I get in both columnB and columnC a list of TRUE and FALSE values. But what do you mean by "delete visible rows"? And I tried to delete columnB which then also deleted columnC

Comment: does this mean I need to paste special this line across the entire sheet? `=IF(COLUMN()<COUNTIF($A:$A,$A2)+3,IF($A2=$A3,INDIRECT("$B"&ROW()+COLUMN()-3),""),"") ` I did that and excel asks me to select `Paste as: HTML, Unicode, Text`

Comment: Okay I think I'm getting more and more confused here. I've never worked much with excel before and I simply don't know enough about excel commands to be able to properly follow through your suggestions. My bad for being an excel noob. Do you think you could just create a really small sample excel file and upload it here so I can see how your suggestions really work? Otherwise I really don't see how I can get this to work without constantly asking for help each step of the way. Sorry about the trouble and thanks for the help

Comment: So I delete each row with TRUE or each row with FALSE? Because deleting either one makes the value in column C become 0

Comment: Okay I've done that, deleted all of the TRUE rows. Now the FALSE ones all have `=#REF!`

Comment: So is it correct I select under Paste Special,  Paste: Values,  Operation: None. Because after I've done this and deleted all the TRUE rows, in columnC I only get a column of 6s. All of the other sizes have been deleted instead of being merged into a single row

Comment: F2? I don't have a F column so I'm not sure where can I find it. Are the above steps you suggested in the answer meant to merge the values of each ID row into a single row but with the values still intact? Or are they meant to replace with just a single value